# New tab doesn't open on click in headless mode (selenium chromedriver python)

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

There is a button on the website and click on it opens a new tab.
It's working ok in an usual mode and not working in a headless mode. A new tab won't open.

```
driver_app.find_element(By.XPATH, "//XPATH_FOR_EXAMPLE").click()
time.sleep(60) # any delay (waits), its for an example
tabs = driver_app.window_handles  # its always = 1 in headless mode and always = 2 in usual mode
```

I use chromedriver 107.0.5304.62, chrome 107.0.5304.107, selenium 4.1.0

If I click on this button manually in mozilla ff, I see a warning about blocking popup message, which is not in chrome.
I've try add option in chrome options:

```
opts.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
```

It doesn't help. What can i do else?

I've try click in test with javascript, with action chains – it doesn't matter. The count of window handles is always different in modes.

Comment: Can you share a link to the page you working on? Without it your question is missing minimal debugging details...

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't. It's internal corporative site. The new tab contains a simple html page with table and a couple of links and its url ends with .html